# Can I force my web socket not to use SSL even though my site is served under SSL?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, websocket

I have a JavaScript client.

I have a web socket and it is trying to talk to my server.

My web app runs under https and I have used Open SSL for get my certificates.

In my C# I am using the Socket object to receive client requests.

My clients can connect but the when I try to read/parse the headers it is encrypted. (I do not know how to decrypt).

If occured to me if my web socket did not use SSL the problem would go away. But, even if  I set the uri in my client to:

```
var url = "ws://192.168.0.9:8090/Relayer";
```

It is changed to:

```
var url = "wss://192.168.0.9:8090/Relayer";
```

This is my server code:

```
//server starting to listen

serverSocket = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP );
serverSocket.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Any, 8090 ) );
serverSocket.Listen( 128 );
serverSocket.BeginAccept( null, 0, OnAccept, null );


//server responding to Client Request:

private static Socket serverSocket;

private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try
    {
        Socket client = null;
        string headerResponse = "";
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
            var i = client.Receive(buffer);



            //my many attempts to read the data....       

            string unicode = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
            string str = Uri.UnescapeDataString(unicode);
            var outputs = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(unicode);
        }
        if (client != null)
        {
            /* Handshaking and managing ClientSocket */
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Logger.LogVerbose(LoggerNames.Error, ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
        }
    }
}
```

So, can I FORCE my web socket not to use SSL?

Thanks

OKAY
After reading stuff I understand it is not a good idea to mix http and https and ws and wss.

Any ideas to get this working using SSL/wss then that would be good :)

Comment: Look into the [SslStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#examples) class examples on MSDN.

Comment: @JessedeWit thanks. Will do after a good sleep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I force my web socket not to use SSL even though my site is served under SSL?

If your JavaScrip client follows security conventions, then the answer is **no**. The answer is also "it shouldn't".

There are a number of reasons for this, but the following reason is quite enough:

When a user observes that the website is encrypted, they assume that **any private information they share will not be visible to third parties**. This is part of **the promise made by encryption**. However, by allowing clear-text (unencrypted) communication after stating the site is encrypted, **this promise could be broken**.

This is why secure clients will not allow non-encrypted communication (i.e., WebSockets, XHR, etc') within a secure website.

> My clients can connect but the when I try to read/parse the headers it is encrypted. (I do not know how to decrypt).

The encrypted data should be passed through the SSL layer to be decrypted.

Often, many languages will provide an "SSL Socket" abstraction that behaves like a socket but automatically encrypts / decrypts data.

As mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436150/can-i-force-my-web-socket-not-to-use-ssl-even-though-my-site-is-served-under-ssl/57441686#comment101351709_57436150) the [`SslStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=netframework-4.8) might be what you're looking for (see Jesse de Wit's comment).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. After not really being involved with web for a few years I have found it a bit different. I think even if I could bypass ssl I agree I should not and there would be no guarantee it not be stoped in the future. I had looked at the above and it did not work. It appears that OpenSSL does not work well with sslstream object. Also using OpenSSL with a local host web app seems to incur more issues. I am using a raspberry pi. With SIM card attached and I wanted to peer to peer with my own pc. I have/need to use web sockets hence the tcp stuff on the server.

Comment: Why C#? Node.js will offer better community resources, possibly making your project easier to accomplish. C could be more CPU/memory friendly if you’re looking for performance. C# doesn’t seem like a best fit, IMHO. Even Ruby, running the iodine WebSocket server (I’m biased), would probably work better.

Comment: Yes, I do appreciate that. Just that I was familiar with c# and asp.net (core).  I WAS looking at whether to use node.js.  But would I not still be faced with the same issues? I wanted to use web sockets because I could stream images to the front-end in byte arrays rather that base64.  To do that and access remotely via GSM/GPRS I would still need to use SSL?

Comment: Good luck! I hope things work out. Personally I’d probably look into node.js, C and Ruby for web on an embedded device (depending on your needs), IMHO.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I think that there are wonderful SSL ready solutions for node. You won’t be the first running an SSL/TLS WebSocket server on pi using node. I personally use C and Ruby, so I can’t point you to good resources.

Comment: Thanks i shall take a look at node.js and Riby. Thanks for the pointers. have a nice weekend :)

Comment: There is perfect capability in .Net to work with SSL. I would not see a reason to use another language for this. And Ruby is actually less performant than .Net. Anyway, you could create a localhost certificate with openssl if you follow [these steps](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/)

Comment: @JessedeWit , your opinion is perfectly valid. However, I’m not sure if you’re right about the performance issue (especially when using the iodine Ruby WebSocket server). Also, the fact that C# **can** be used, doesn’t make it the best tool for the job. Node offers more community support/packages, Ruby is often faster to code in and C offers better resource management for the embedded system environment (which probably isn’t important if C# was originally chosen). Sure, C# can also be used, I’m not against it, I’m just offering my opinion.